# my TRAMP connection (?error) to org file has duplicated my org entries

Tags: org-mode

now I have a file of a lot of such structure:

```
* one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: one
:END:
* one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: one
:END:
* one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: one
:END:
* one
:PROPERTIES:
:CUSTOM_ID: one
:END:
* two
BROWN FOX
* two
BROWN FOX
* two
BROWN FOX
* two
BROWN FOX
```

how can I revert it back so there is only one of every entity?

Comment: How is this related to Tramp?

Comment: Michael Albinus I believe this behavior is due to error I recieved with Tramp, it said something like "decoding ..." but I'm not sure so I've put a question sign respectively

Comment: If you want to let it investigate from Tramp pov, pls give a recipe. Otherwise, if you want only know how to repair the org-mode file, you might remove the `tramp` tag from your question. It wouldn't be related then.

Comment: Unless you have a backup (one you took manually, one that Emacs took atomatically or one that your version control system provides), then your only recourse is to manually delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a better-than-nothing solution: a python script

```python
filename = ""
output_filename = ""


with open(filename, mode="r") as f:
    tmp = f.read()


blocks = tmp.split('\n*')


output_list = []
for block in blocks:
    if block not in output_list:
        output_list.append(block)

with open(output_filename, mode="w") as f:
    f.write("\n*".join(output_list))
```

I hope this helps someone